# Visual studio unit test for .NET framework 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am currently using visual studio 2019. I have an c# windows form application that runs on .NET framework 4.0 and I would like to use MS unit testing framework to carry out the unit testing for my software. However, the [TestClass] and [TestMethod] attribute does not seem to be available for .NET framework 4.0.

Below shows the current error that I am facing. Would it be possible to carry out unit testing for .NET framework 4.0 ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add the reference?

Comment: I couldnt find the reference for the System.Runtime version

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testclassattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0), you need the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework` DLL.

Comment: changing the .NET framework to 4.7.2 fixes the error. But i want to test using .NET 4.0 framework

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 is no longer supported [see for details](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/) - you should consider upgrade your code base

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem. After launching it with VS2010, right-click the project -> Add reference -> .NET -> find the assemblies, and it works fine.